# R - draw new layer behind current plot

Tags: r, plot

Just curious, when plotting in R, **one can easily change the order of the executive code to change the order** of those "*layer*" on the plot, e.g.

```
plot(x, type = "n")
lines(y)
points(x)
```

to get `x` over the `y`. Are there any way to do it in an `adhoc` way, e.g.

```
plot(x)
lines(y, behind = TRUE) # fictional option behind
```

Comment: why not start with `plot(y, type="l")` in the first place?

Comment: No. The base graphics plotting model is "ink on paper". There's no "behind" or "erase" action that fits in with that model.

Comment: use ggplot(). You have clear control of how a plot is built up, with whatever you ask for first going at the bottom.

Comment: @SimonG this's just for illustration, my main ideas is plotting something later but still stay behind the previous plot. In a more complex plot, this would be more obvious.

Comment: Is there really a necessity for this? I cannot really imagine to be honest. To me it seems that such situations can usually be avoided by proper planning.

Comment: @SimonG you're right, proper planning to achieve that is also what I stated in the question. But, for convenience and...maybe fun when playing with the plot.

Answer (score 5):

While there isn't explicitly a `behind` option or layers in `plot`, an easy way to overlay two plots might be using the `add = TRUE` option in `plot`. Here is an example with artificial data:

```
# Load sp package for creating artificial data
library(sp)

# Create sample town points
towns <- data.frame(lon = sample(100), lat = sample(100))
towns <- SpatialPoints(towns)

# Create sample polygon grid
grd <- GridTopology(c(1,1), c(10,10), c(10,10))
polys <- as.SpatialPolygons.GridTopology(grd)

# Plot polygons
plot(polys)

# Add towns (in red colour)
plot(towns, add = TRUE, col = 'red')
```

[image: First Example]

As another example, you can plot lines on different layers in `ggplot` and `melt` like this:

```
a <- c(3, 6, 16, 17, 11, 21)    
b <- c(0.3, 2.3, 9, 9, 5 ,12)
c <- c(3, 7, 9, 7, 6, 10)
dat <- data.frame(a=a,b=b,c=c)
dat <- melt(dat)
```

Add an explicit 'x' variable to our data frame:

```
dat$x <- rep(1:6,times=3)
```

Then just plot the graph:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=value)) + 
    geom_line(aes(colour=variable)) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=colours) + 
    labs(x="time[h]",y="a",colour="") + 
    opts(title="bla")
```

Finally, there is explicit support for layers in other packages, such as in `PBSmapping` for maps.

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, and `c`?

Comment: @RichardScriven I've added some arbitrary values for them to the solution, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The `add = TRUE` is common usage, but what if you want the newly added plot stay behind the current plot, that is what I'm looking for. But as @BondeDust said, it's not possible.

Comment: @KinhNguyen you could just change your order of operations or use a different plotting function/package.

Comment: @NerdLife I stated that in the question.

Comment: @KinhNguyen You mentioned the other packages? I'm just stating your options here and giving you examples of how to do it...